# Jquery highlight effect on new rows

Tags: php, javascript

I have an AJAX grid which refreshes every 60 seconds showing new rows. It's a very basic XMLHttpRequest() grid which pulls data from a php file. I've checked all the internet but still haven't found a solution to how to implement this jQuery highlight effect on newly added rows after each refreshing:
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight:

What would be the best strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output new rows from your server with an extra class, say `tohighlight`. In your ajax success handler (in the JS), do something like:

```
...
success: function(data) {

  // ... your code to refresh the grid with new rows etc..

  // highlight new rows
  $('.tohighlight').highlight();

  // remove the tohighlight class, so these rows wont be highlighted after your next refresh
  $('.tohighlight').removeClass('tohighlight');

}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

When you include the data in your php file, create a function (still in your php file) that applies the effect to the data, so when you pull it from the main page, it will already have the effect.